# drupal_set_title not setting $title variable

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to use drupal_set_title in my node.tpl.php but the text I'm setting the title to is only showing up in the $head_title variable and not the $title variable. The $title variable is still set to the node's title.

This is in Drupal 7. I've used drupal_set_title multiple times like this in Drupal 6 and it has worked perfectly.

Comment: `$head_title` isn't a standard variable for `node.tpl.php`, did you mean [`html.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php)? (see [`node.tpl.php` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php) for a list of available variables)

Comment: $head_title is being used in html.tpl.php and it gets set properly, but $title in node.tpl.php is not set correctly.

Comment: Gotcha, where abouts are you using `drupal_set_title`? Is it in a theme/module and if so which function?

Comment: It is being used in my theme's node.tpl.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clive got me pointed in the correct direction, but I couldn't get the preprocess_node to work, so I had to use preprocess_page instead. Here's the code that works:

```
function mycooltheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
    if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'news'){
        drupal_set_title('News');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason this isn't working is because of where you're calling it from. Drupal's templating system works by building up variables (of which `$title` is one) and passing them in to the template file.

By the time you get to `node.tpl.php` the `$title` variable, which is only available in the scope of that file, is already set in stone. So while calling `drupal_set_title` will work to change the `$head_title` for `html.tpl.php` (which is called later than `node.tpl.php`, it can't change the variables of the template file you're calling the code from.

Your best bet would be to put a preprocess function in your theme's `template.php` which sets the title before the template file is processed:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  drupal_set_title('A new title');
}
```

If that still doesn't work try explicitly setting `$vars['title']` = 'A new title';` in the same preprocess function.

The best option would be to write a very small custom module and implement `hook_node_view()` which is called way before the template file comes into the process and should always work:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $lang_code) {
  drupal_set_title('A new title');
}
```